# NSPredicate compound using NOT in relationships

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nspredicate

I have the following predicate which isn't working as expected:

```
isHistoric == 0 AND (NOT ANY singleToMany.name ==[cd] "searchword")
```

I am expecting any objects that have a .name of 'searchword' in their singleToMany relationship will not appear in the results... but they do.

If I flip this on its head and remove the NOT - I just return the one result I want to not get using NOT! [if that makes sense] meaning:

```
isHistoric == 0 AND (ANY singleToMany.name ==[cd] "searchword")
```

returns the one result I don't want to appear in the first predicate example.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
isHistoric == 0 AND (NONE singleToMany.name ==[cd] "searchword")
```

The docs say that `NONE` is equivalent to `NOT (ANY ...)`. Note the placement of the parentheses. So, the above should be equivalent to:

```
isHistoric == 0 AND NOT (ANY singleToMany.name ==[cd] "searchword")
```

Comment: Neither of those work either... Just don't get it. I've tried so many combinations. Other threads on this same subject suggest checking if the relationships are set up correctly - not sure what I should be checking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
isHistoric == 0 AND singleToMany.name NOT LIKE [cd] "searchword"
```

Comment: Nope. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'